# What is Indy WriteLn and ReadLn string max length?

Tags: sockets, indy10

Is there a limit in the length of the string sent and read with the Indy methods `WriteLn` and `ReadLn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TIdIOHandler.WriteLn()` is limited only by available memory.  However, do note that it appends an `EOL` (`#13#10`) to the end of the input string, producing a new string which is a copy of the original, and then it converts that copy to a `TIdBytes` for sending.  So more memory will be used than just what you pass in.  I'm sure this can be optimized better in the future.

`TIdIOHandler.ReadLn()` has an optional `AMaxLineLength` parameter that is set to `-1` by default.  If it is set to `< 0`, the `TIdIOHandler.MaxLineLength` property will be used instead, which is set to `16384` bytes by default. You can set `(A)MaxLineLength` higher if needed, or you can even set it to `0` to disable the limit completely.  If `(A)MaxLineLength` is set to `> 0` and incoming data exceeds that limit, the subsequent behavior depends on the `TIdIOHandler.MaxLineAction` property:

- `maException` (the default): an `EIdReadLnMaxLineLengthExceeded` is raised, and the received bytes will remain in the `TIdIOHandler.InputBuffer` for subsequent reads.
- `maSplit`: exactly `(A)MaxLineLength` number of bytes will be extracted from the `TIdIOHandler.InputBuffer` and returned as a `String`, and the `TIdIOHander.ReadLnSplit` property will be set to `True`.  The leftover bytes will remain in the `TIdIOHandler.InputBuffer` for subsequent reads.

Comment: Thanks for the precise and detailed reply. I have another question, I don't know if I have to open another post: what is the difference between `TCPClient->IOHandler->MaxLineLength = 0;` and `TCPClient->Socket->MaxLineLength = 0;`? I mean: the difference between using `Socket` and `IOHandler`. It seems that I can use both in the same way at the same place.

Comment: @user3680100 "*what is the difference between [IOHandler] and [Socket]?*" - when the `IOHandler` is assigned a `TIdIOHandlerSocket`-derived object, `Socket` is set to the same object, otherwise it is set to `nil`. So `Socket` is just a shortcut to avoid having to typecast the `IOHandler` whenever socket-specific functionality needs to be accessed.

Comment: When I set `TCPClient->IOHandler->MaxLineLength = 0;` or `TCPClient->Socket->MaxLineLength = 0;` I get the error `Project CMRemoteViewer.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x0041b484: write of address 0x000000b8'.`

Comment: sorry..... I'm messing up comments.... not sure what to delete without doing other damages ... I apologize

Comment: I have found the error: the TCPClient was not connectet when I set the property `MaxLineLength`